# Tomcat http to https redirect with custom cache control header

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

We have a spring boot application deployed in tomcat. We want tomcat to redirect http requests to https. But we want to disable tomcat adding 'Cache-Control:private' to all response headers by default.

For rest API  requests we want the default cache header added by spring boot.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma:no-cache
Expires:0
```

but from tomcat it is

```
Cache-Control:private
Cache-Control:private
Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 19:00:00 EST
```

Seems as if 'Expires' header will give same no cache effect. But would like to know if there is way to stop tomcat from adding cache header. For static files also the header is 'private, max-age=2592000, public' instead of 'max-age=2592000, public'.  Below are my tomcat configurations and code to add custom cache header for static files.

server.xml

```
... 
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443"/>
....
 <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" scheme="https" compression="on"
     sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" sslCipherSuite="SHA1/SHA2"
     acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
     keystoreFile="mycertificate" keystorePass="mypassword" server="Server">
```

web.xml

```
...
<security-constraint>
     <web-resource-collection>
         <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </web-resource-collection>
     <user-data-constraint>
         <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
     </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
...
```

Custom Caching

```
@Configuration
public class LocaleConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/content/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/content/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(30, TimeUnit.DAYS).cachePublic());
    }
}
```

Comment: In prod we had a azure load balancer running on IIS. For static files this removed the 'Cache-Control:private' so the files were cached properly. Haven't found any way to achieve the same in tomcat.